# jQuery multiple click handlers..how to ensure order of firing?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, live

I have 2 click handlers binded to an element like so:

in the file which contains the control I am binding to, I have the first handler, which does some functionality specific to that control

```
$("#mycontrol").live("click", function() { alert("foo"); });
```

In the main page which uses that control, I have another handler binding to that element for page specific functionality

```
$("#mycontrol").live("click", function() { alert("bar"); });
```

I use 'live' because AJAX calls are changing the control all the time, so the handlers will be reregistered.  However I need a way so that "foo" happens before "bar" consistently...any suggestions?

Comment: Why is the functionality changing when the Ajax is loaded?  Why not hide the first input and show the second, with a different id?

Comment: im using ASP AJAX with a datagrid that has checkboxes on it.  I want to rebind the client side click handler to the checkboxes w/ jquery when the table is sorted or refreshed, for example.  The click handler specific to the control itself sets some data up depending on the checkbox state
the handler on the page does other stuff with the checkbox state..but the control's handler needs to fire first because it sets up the data that will be needed by the 2nd handler in this case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to order events bound with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290254/how-to-order-events-bound-with-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try combining the click events into one:

```
function foo() { alert("foo"); }
function bar() { alert("bar"); }
$("#mycontrol").live("click", function(){ foo.call(this); bar.call(this); });
```

Comment: i ended up putting a stub JS function in the subcontrol's file..and the click handler calls that after it's own work

and in the main page, i override the stub function w/ the page specific functionality

Answer (score 5):

How's about:

```
$("#mycontrol").live("click", doFooBar);

function doFooBar() {
    alert("foo");
    alert("bar");
}
```

Comment: this won't work because both the control and the main page both contain the live handler..

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the following:

```
var arrEventHandlers = [];

function registerClickEvent(fnCallback)
{
    arrEventHandlers.push(fnCallback);
}

registerClickEvent (function () { alert ("Foo"); });
registerClickEvent (function () { alert ("Bar"); });

function clickHandler ()
{
    for (var i = 0, size = arrEventHandlers.length; i < size; i++)
    {
        arrEventHandlers[i].apply (...);
    }
}

$("#mycontrol").live("click", clickHandler);
```

Comment: i like this, but it's overkill for this instance..if i have to do this more time, i think i will go with a solution like this