# How to override event.stopPropagation(),preventDefault().stopImmediatePropagation()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jira, jira-plugin

I am trying to modify Jira Tempo plugin's plan work form. So in the tempo time sheet page
I have a button who has 2 actions bind-ed, one is a click action and one is  a focus out.
the click action opens a popup. and the focus out verifies the form in the popup. I need the clik action to be executed first and then the focus out.

The problem is when the popup opens there is a call to all of the three functions.
`event.stopPropagation().preventDefault().stopImmediatePropagation();` so the focus out does not fire in chrome.

In IE10 and Firefox works great.

Can i override jQuery basic function of`event.stopPropagation().preventDefault().stopImmediatePropagation()`  to do not apply for that button? 
all three, maybe?

I tried this:

```
(function () {
jQuery.Event.prototype = {
    isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse,
isPropagationStopped: returnFalse,
isImmediatePropagationStopped: returnFalse,
    stopPropagation: function () {
        if (jQuery('#tempo-plan-button').hasClass(this.currentTarget.className)) {

        } else {
            var e = this.originalEvent;

            this.isPropagationStopped = returnTrue;

            if (e && e.stopPropagation) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        }
    },
    preventDefault: function () {
        if (jQuery('#tempo-plan-button').hasClass(this.currentTarget.className)) {

        } else {
            var e = this.originalEvent;

            this.isDefaultPrevented = returnTrue;

            if (e && e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    },
    stopImmediatePropagation: function () {
        if (jQuery('#tempo-plan-button').hasClass(this.currentTarget.className)) {

        } else {
            var e = this.originalEvent;

            this.isImmediatePropagationStopped = returnTrue;

            if (e && e.stopImmediatePropagation) {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }

            this.stopPropagation();
        }
    }

};
function returnFalse() {
    return false;
}
function returnTrue() {
    return true;
}
})();
```

UPDATE:

I don't have control on what the click function does, but i have control on the focus out, I have made some test and i looks like Chrome does not see the focus out event, because the element is hidden before the focus out occurs ( it is a popup button).
I managed to call my functions with mouse out event but this does not work on IE  so I have to bind separate event listener for IE and Chrome,Firefox,Safari.
Can you help with some browser detection examples.

UPDATE 2:

My problem solved with a different listener to the popup element. ex:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var currentUser = null;
var selected = null;
var opened = null;
var formOpened = null;
var activityField = null;
var activitySelected = null;
var popupBody = null;
var formOpened = null;
var periodCheckbox = null;
var dateField = null;
var endDateField = null;
var plannedHours = null;
var periodselected = null;
var days = 1;
var startdate = 0;
var enddate = 0;
var planButton = $('#tempo-plan-button');
//this is the default LM-Holiday activity ID set this
value to corespond with the value on jira tempo form.
var holidayid = "10100";
var holidaysLeft = 21; /*
 $('#tempo-plan-button').click(function () {
 alert("click event");
 });
 $('#tempo-plan-button').focusin(function () {
 alert("focus event");
 });
 $('#tempo-plan-button').hover(function () {
 alert("hover event");

 });
 $('#tempo-plan-button').mouseleave(function () {
 alert("mouse leave event");

 });
 $('#tempo-plan-button').mouseout(function () {
 alert("mouse out event");

 }); */
$('body').one('focus', 'div[class="aui-popup aui-dialog"]', function (event) {
    $('div[class="aui-popup aui-dialog"]').each(function () {
        popupBody = $(this).find(".dialog-components");
        if ($(this).find(".dialog-title").hasClass("tempo-add-button") === false) {
            i = 0;
            j = 0;
            $(popupBody).find(".dialog-page-menu li").each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr("class") === "page-menu-item selected") {
                    button = $(this).find('.item-button');
                    if ((button).text() === "Internal") {
                        selected = i;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            });
            $(popupBody).find(".dialog-panel-body").each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
                    opened = j;
                    formOpened = $(this).find('form');
                }
                j++;
            });
            if (selected === null) {
                i = 0;
                j = 0;
                $(popupBody).find(".dialog-page-menu li").click(function () {
                    $(popupBody).find(".dialog-page-menu li").each(function () {
                        if ($(this).attr("class") === "page-menu-item selected") {
                            button = $(this).find('.item-button');
                            if ((button).text() === "Internal") {
                                selected = i;
                            }
                        }
                        i++;
                    });
                    $(popupBody).find(".dialog-panel-body").each(function () {
                        if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
                            opened = j;
                            formOpened = $(this).find('form');
                        }
                        j++;
                    });
                    if (selected === opened) {
                        activityField = $(formOpened).find('.tempo-activity-picker.select');
                        periodCheckbox = $(formOpened).find('.showperiod.tempo-show-period');
                        dateField = $(formOpened).find(' input[name="date"]');
                        endDateField = $(formOpened).find('input[name="enddate"]');
                        plannedHours = $(formOpened).find('input[name="time"]');
                        days = 1;
                        $(activityField).change(function () {
                            activitySelected = $(this).val();
                        });

                        $(periodCheckbox).change(function () {
                            if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
                                periodselected = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                periodselected = false;

                            }
                        });
                        $(dateField).change(function () {
                            if (periodselected) {
                                startdate = parseDate($(this).val());
                                enddate = parseDate($(endDateField).val());
                            } else {
                                days = 1;
                            }
                            ;
                        });
                        $(endDateField).change(function () {
                            startdatestring = $(dateField).val();
                            enddatestring = $(this).val();
                            startdate = parseDate(startdatestring);
                            enddate = parseDate(enddatestring);
                        });
                        $(plannedHours).off("focusin");
                        $(plannedHours).focusin(function () {
                            if (activitySelected === holidayid) {
                                if (periodselected) {
                                    days = calcBusinessDays(startdate, enddate);

                                    if (holidaysLeft >= days) {
                                        holidaysLeft = holidaysLeft - days;
                       alert("Mai ai " + holidaysLeft + " zile de concediu ramase!");
                      $(popupBody).find('button[accesskey="s"]').removeAttr('disabled');
                                    }
                                    else {
         $(popupBody).find('button[accesskey="s"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
         alert('trebuie sa selectezi o perioada mai mica de' + holidaysLeft + 'de zile');
                                    }
                                } else
                                {
                                    if (holidaysLeft >= days) {
                                        holidaysLeft = holidaysLeft - days;
                                 alert("Mai ai " + holidaysLeft + " zile de concediu ramase!");
                        $(popupBody).find('button[accesskey="s"]').removeAttr('disabled');
                                    }
                                    else {
                 $(popupBody).find('button[accesskey="s"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
               alert('trebuie sa selectezi o perioada mai mica de' + holidaysLeft + 'de zile');
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                j = 0;
                $(popupBody).find(".dialog-panel-body").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
                        opened = j;
                        formOpened = $(this).find('form');
                    }
                    j++;
                });
                if (selected === opened) {
                    activityField = $(formOpened).find('.tempo-activity-picker.select');
                    periodCheckbox = $(formOpened).find('.showperiod.tempo-show-period');
                    dateField = $(formOpened).find(' input[name="date"]');
                    endDateField = $(formOpened).find('input[name="enddate"]');
                    plannedHours = $(formOpened).find('input[name="time"]');
                    days = 1;
                    $(activityField).change(function () {
                        activitySelected = $(this).val();
                    });

                    $(periodCheckbox).change(function () {
                        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
                            periodselected = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            periodselected = false;

                        }
                    });
                    $(dateField).change(function () {
                        if (periodselected) {
                            startdate = parseDate($(this).val());
                            enddate = parseDate($(endDateField).val());
                        } else {
                            days = 1;
                        }
                        ;
                    });
                    $(endDateField).change(function () {
                        startdatestring = $(dateField).val();
                        enddatestring = $(this).val();
                        startdate = parseDate(startdatestring);
                        enddate = parseDate(enddatestring);
                    });
                    $(plannedHours).off("focusin");
                    $(plannedHours).focusin(function () {
                        if (activitySelected === holidayid) {
                            if (periodselected) {
                                days = calcBusinessDays(startdate, enddate);

                                if (holidaysLeft >= days) {
                                    holidaysLeft = holidaysLeft - days;
               alert("Mai ai " + holidaysLeft + " zile de concediu ramase!");
               $(popupBody).find('button[accesskey="s"]').removeAttr('disabled');
                                }
                                else {
                       $(popupBody).find('button[accesskey="s"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                alert('trebuie sa selectezi o perioada mai mica de' + holidaysLeft + 'de zile');
                                }
                            } else
                            {
                                if (holidaysLeft >= days) {
                                    holidaysLeft = holidaysLeft - days;
                              alert("Mai ai " + holidaysLeft + " zile de concediu ramase!");
                         $(popupBody).find('button[accesskey="s"]').removeAttr('disabled');
                                }
                                else {
                    $(popupBody).find('button[accesskey="s"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          alert('trebuie sa selectezi o perioada mai mica de' + holidaysLeft + 'de zile');
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            ;
        }
        ;
        return false;
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: location.protocol + '//' + location.host + "/rest/api/2/myself",
        success: function (response) {
            currentUser = $.parseJSON(response);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("Eroare" + response.result);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
 function calcBusinessDays(dDate1, dDate2) { // input given as Date objects
var iWeeks, iDateDiff, iAdjust = 0;
if (dDate2 < dDate1)
    return -1; // error code if dates transposed
var iWeekday1 = dDate1.getDay(); // day of week
var iWeekday2 = dDate2.getDay();
iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 === 0) ? 7 : iWeekday1; // change Sunday from 0 to 7
iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 === 0) ? 7 : iWeekday2;
if ((iWeekday1 > 5) && (iWeekday2 > 5))
    iAdjust = 1; // adjustment if both days on weekend
iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday1; // only count weekdays
iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday2;

// calculate differnece in weeks (1000mS * 60sec * 60min * 24hrs * 7 days = 604800000)
iWeeks = Math.floor((dDate2.getTime() - dDate1.getTime()) / 604800000);

if (iWeekday1 <= iWeekday2) {
    iDateDiff = (iWeeks * 5) + (iWeekday2 - iWeekday1);
} else {
    iDateDiff = ((iWeeks + 1) * 5) - (iWeekday1 - iWeekday2);
}

iDateDiff -= iAdjust // take into account both days on weekend

return (iDateDiff + 1); // add 1 because dates are inclusive
}
function parseDate(s) {
var lastSlash = s.lastIndexOf("/");
var years = s.substring(lastSlash + 1);
years = "20" + years;
s = s.replaceAt(lastSlash + 1, years);
var pattern = /(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)$/;
var result = s.replace(pattern, function (match, p1, p2, p3) {
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',
 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    return (months.indexOf(p2) + 1) + "/" + (p1) + "/" + p3;
});
return new Date(result);
}
String.prototype.replaceAt = function (index, character) {
 return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index + character.length);
};
function propStopped(event) {
var msg = "";
if (event.isPropagationStopped()) {
    msg = "called";
} else {
    msg = "not called";
}
alert(msg);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is a bad practice to do, and your `returnTrue`/`false`  are complete not making any sense

Comment: @Andreas Furster I added those from jQuery library. 
So, these three methods are already called, in an on click event, but i can't modify that. instead i want to override them, to do not apply to my #tempo-plan-button element.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```js
Event.prototype.stopPropagation = function(){ alert('123') }
$('input').on('click',function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' value='click' />
```

Comment: Yes @aleha , something like that, but i don't want to be executed for that element. and i don't have access to the click event script. so i can't modify that. and also all three methods are called in the click event. so I must skip all three for that button.

Comment: just overriding these methods using Event.prototype object to empty function wont help? `Event.prototype.stopPropagation = function(){  }`

Comment: Nope, nothing changed.

Comment: so it was the problem with the event itself the focus out was not trigered at all in chrome, but mouseout is trigered, but now if i use the second IE is not seeing the event... so i need a workaround? any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

From the question, it is unclear as to which code you control. I am reading between the lines that perhaps you control the function bound to the click event for the button, but you do not control the function bound to the focusout event, which is why you need to work around those calls.

If you want to control of execution of the events and make sure that yours happen first, it's possible to do this with something like [jQuery.bindUp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4742655/2220556), just so long as the events are of the same type. In that way, you don't care if the other handler tries to call stopPropagation etc. because your handler will get to execute first anyway.

Given that, is it possible to restructure your code so that the logic you control (the part which needs to happen first!) is of the same event type as the existing event handler, and then use jQuery.bindUp to ensure that it gets executed before the event handler that you do not control? You can still bind to the click event if you need it, just so long as the dependent business logic is moved to the focusout event.

(If my assumptions are not correct, it would be helpful if you could update the question to describe the problem constraints in more detail.)

Comment: thanks, for the answer,but really my problem was that the focus out was not seen by chrome, and now i have to bind different event listener for every browser. do you have some example, how to detect browser and according to it bind different event listeners?

Comment: @AlexRobert, it would be easier for people to help you if you isolate the problem and (say) put together a jsfiddle that demonstrates the exact issue. That process might also lead you to discovering the problem yourself!

Comment: i can only put my code whitch is inserted in this question to, the other code is in Atlassian Jira platform. and can't access it.
i resolved the problem using another event listener.