# Capture all click events using jquery regardless of elements click event having stopPropagation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to have a global event capture so that if an element has a click event, and stopPropagation is used, the global event capture still fires and runs its own code.

The global event capture is for a jquery plugin that knows nothing about any other jquery/javascript on the page.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300965/how-to-override-event-stoppropagation-preventdefault-stopimmediatepropagatio

Comment: Thanks. I think @CertainPerformance solution is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will not be possible if a similar listener has been added to `document` before your code has had a chance to run, *and* that listener calls `stopImmediatePropagation`, but luckily, such things are quite rare.

All you need to do is add a click listener to `document` in the *capturing* phase, so that your listener runs as soon as it possibly can (it will run before any bubbling listeners fire, and will run before any capturing listeners, *except* capturing listeners on `document`):

```js
document.addEventListener(
  'click',
  () => {
    console.log('global click detected');
  },
  true // <-- very important: trigger listener in capturing phase
);

document.querySelector('#foo').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('foo clicked, stopPropagation called');
});
```

```html
<div id="foo">click</div>
```

Example snippet where the "global click detected" wouldn't work, due to a capturing listener on `document` that calls `stopImmediatePropagation`:

```js
document.addEventListener(
  'click',
  (e) => {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.stopPropagation();
  },
  true
);

// cannot intercept click now, due to stopImmediatePropagation
document.addEventListener(
  'click',
  () => {
    console.log('global click detected');
  },
  true
);
```

```html
<div id="foo">click</div>
```

Note that adding listeners in the capturing phase cannot be done with jQuery - have to use standard Javascript for that.

This sort of technique is very handy for intercepting events when you can't control other code on the page.