# disabled button in first event won't fire the second one

Tags: javascript, jquery-events

I have a checkout button, and when the user accepts the terms, in the first event I set the button to disable and then submit the form. In this case, the second event that was set on the button won't fire anymore.

```
$cache.opcSubmit.prop('disabled', true);
$cache.opc.submit();
```

[image: first event regular one]

the second (live) event will not fire when that code above runs that is in the first event.

The second event was set like this :

```
$(document).on('click', '.continue-step button[type="submit"]', function () {
    $(this).data('event', 'doSomething');
}
```

The thing is that I cannot place the second event up because it is using a library that it will init events after 1 second to be sure was loaded.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does the order of the events matter?  Can you run yours first?  The following discusses how to attach an event as the first event. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742610/attaching-jquery-event-handlers-so-that-they-are-triggered-first

Comment: As i told in the question i cannot do that because the events are inited after 1 second `setInterval(initializeTracking, 1000);` so it will always get second due to library loading

Comment: You can set your own interval and only attach your event after the library has finished loading.

Comment: @cse it does nothing that blocks . this doent even fire .. that is the problem