# Block all mouse events except scroll

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I'm using some kind of *loading component* (actually a absolute positioned div with a strong transparency and a loading spinner) to disable some inputs / areas and show they are loading.

But if its positioned above a scrollable element (div), I'd still like to be able to scroll it (using mousewheel / touch-input).

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
<div style="position: relative; display: flex">
  <div
    style="
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: white;
      opacity: 0.5;
      pointer-events: none;
    "
  ></div>

  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: auto">
    <div style="height: 1000px">
      <button onclick="alert('YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME!')">
        YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: auto">
    <div style="height: 1000px">
      <button onclick="alert('YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME!')">
        YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME, TOO!
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="position: relative; display: flex">
  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: auto">
    <div style="height: 1000px">
      <button onclick="alert('Im still useable!')">
        I'm still useable
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Using `pointer-events: none;` sure works for scroll-events but does not block e.g. the button from being pressed. How to achieve this?

In this solution the content is blocked but not scrollable, too:

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
<div style="position: relative; display: flex">
  <div
    style="
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: white;
      opacity: 0.5;
    "
  ></div>

  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: auto">
    <div style="height: 1000px">
      <button onclick="alert('YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME!')">
        YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: auto">
    <div style="height: 1000px">
      <button onclick="alert('YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME!')">
        YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME, TOO!
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="position: relative; display: flex">
  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: auto">
    <div style="height: 1000px">
      <button onclick="alert('Im still useable!')">
        I'm still useable
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is a strongly simplfied minimal repro. I want the semi-transparent div to be a common component that can just be placed above any content without knowing / being able to modify it.

Edit:

Just for clarification, since most of the solutions / suggestions are trying to adjusted the faded **content**: I want to *loaded-div* to be a universal control to block its underlaying content from being useable while the user can still see it - a classical loader. **But** I still want the content to be scrollable, so the user can still *check* the whole visible content (while not being able to interact with it). This comes with the following requirements:

- I do not know the content or the amount of scrollable divs inside it
- I want to adjusted the content as less as somehow possbile (since I do not know how it might behave / remove my handlers etc.)
- Accordingly some handling on the window (as already suggested) might be possible?

Comment: Why don't you apply `pointer-events: none;` to an element in the scroll content or to the button itself? Also I think its better to actually [disable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) your inputs.

Comment: Just edited my initial post. I want to create a universal component that should not modify any of the content it is placed above.

Comment: Unsure what this means. If you place an absolute "invisible" element above other elements then scrolling will never be possible

Comment: Sure this _could_ work. E.g. setting `pointer-events: none;` - but this unblocks all events. Maybe I can catch the scroll-event and send a fake-event to my parent / the next element under the pointer? I just don't have a clue how to implement this.

Comment: @tris set pointer events to none then use js to listen for scroll and touchscroll events

Comment: @tris what if we set the position of 1st div to absolute and 2nd to relative? will that work for you ? or just set top: unset;, and then add pointer even none to just button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added more functions for you now check again if no lemme know

```js
var scrollBlocker = document.getElementById('scrollBlocker');

        // Block all mouse events except scrolling
        window.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
            // Check if it's not a scroll action or touch event
            if (event.button !== 1 && !event.touches) {
                event.preventDefault();
                scrollBlocker.style.pointerEvents = 'auto'; // Enable mouse events temporarily
            }
        });

        window.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Disable right-click context menu
        });

        // Re-enable mouse events on mouseup (when scrolling ends)
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
            scrollBlocker.style.pointerEvents = 'none'; // Block mouse events again
        });

        // Handle touch events
        window.addEventListener('touchstart', function (event) {
            // Disable touch events temporarily
            event.preventDefault();
            scrollBlocker.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
        });

        window.addEventListener('touchend', function () {
            scrollBlocker.style.pointerEvents = 'none'; // Block touch events again
        });
```

```html
    <div style="position: relative">
        <div
            style="
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                background-color: white;
                opacity: 0;
                pointer-events: auto;
            "
            id="scrollBlocker"
        ></div>
        <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: auto">
            <div style="height: 1000px">
                <button onclick="alert('You cannot trigger me!');">
                    You cannot trigger me
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The button is still clickable in your solution.

Comment: you don't want to click the button?

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea of the loader. The faded content should not be useable (except scroll / touch-scroll) I've extended my question a bit more to make it clearer.

Comment: check now I have updated the code

Comment: I made a small change in your html that is added `id="scrollBlocker"`

Comment: Doesn't work for touch-events (with mobile I cannot scroll) and is starting to get pretty hacky. Now mousedown would trigger on my blocked content. I want to make sure **NO** event (except scrolling) is possible.

Comment: I have added more functions for you now check again if no lemme know

Comment: Why don't you loop over all controls on the page and just set their events to something that does nothing or set it to null?
I'm not very good in JS, but this is how I handle internet disconnection on my Android applications

Comment: Appreciate but he intends to prevent all mouse events except for scrolling, but it appears that your code isn't functioning correctly in any way

Comment: Since this is the best idea imho, I'll mark it as an answer. The solution isn't perfect yet, but yes. Probably the way to go is checking / handing events on window-level.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `loading` class to the element that is loading, then visually disable the inputs within that by giving them opacity and disable their pointing events.

```
#loader{
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
}
.loading label, .loading input, .loading button{
  opacity: 0.2;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.loader').show();
  let pos = $('#content').position();
  $('.loader').css('top', pos.top);
  $('.loader').css('left', pos.left);
  $('#content').addClass('loading');
});
```

Keep the loader itself as small as the 'animation' so the user can still interact with the content.

https://jsfiddle.net/zy0wup4a/2/

I myself also use this approach in one of my applications, infinite `.content` can be in loading state.

**Edit:**
To handle inline and attached click handlers on the div itself I came up with the following two functions to be called when showing the loader and after closing the loader:

```
$.fn.backupAndPreventOnClick = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
    let $el = $(this);
    if($el.prop('onclick')){
        $el.data('onClick', $el.prop('onclick'));
    }
    
    $el[0].onclick = function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      return false;
        };
  });
};

$.fn.resetOnClick = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
    let $el = $(this);
    $el.removeProp('onclick');
    if(!$el.data('onClick'))
        return;
      
        $el[0].onclick = $el.data('onClick');
    $el.removeData('onClick');
  });
};
```

See a second fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/amgcyLh1/

By using the onclick property itself, we can easily block other listeners. An other solution would be to use a jQuery plugin to register the function as first in the queue. For example [Attaching jQuery event handlers so that they are triggered first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742610/attaching-jquery-event-handlers-so-that-they-are-triggered-first)

Comment: Ah, you're just setting "pointer-events: none;" to your  children's inputs. That a great solution - I tend to mark it as an answer. But if e.g. my div (that should still be scrollable) has a click-event, that wouldn't be blocked (https://jsfiddle.net/psm4rn17/).  I want to make sure **EVERYTHING** but scroll gets blocked.

Comment: @tris see my edit and second fiddle to handle inline click events on the 'loading' div itself.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you loop over all controls and disable all events except for scroll?

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    //Code
    event.preventDefault();
});

document.addEventListener("wheel", function(event) {
    //Code
});
```

This is an example of how you can handle events, you can add them to your controls using a for loop for example

I'm not good in JS but this is how I handle internet disconnection on my Android & iOS applications.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a completely other approach.

Place the loader exactly on top of the content that is loading, add fake scrollable div to it, and pass the scrolling to the real content div.

I don't know what the downside is of this approach. Although it is not a complete answer now because only vertical scrolling is handled :)

**Version 1**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loader").css('height', $('#content').height());
    $("#loader").css('width', $('#content').width());
    $("#loader-scroll").css('height', $('#content')[0].scrollHeight);

});

$('#loader').on('scroll', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  $('#content')[0].scrollTop = event.target.scrollTop;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position: relative">
  <div id="loader"
    style="
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: red;
      opacity: 0.5;
      z-index: 9999;
        overflow:auto;
      
    "
  ><div id="loader-scroll">
  </div></div>

  <div id="content" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: auto">
    <div style="height: 1000px">
      <button onclick="alert('YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME!')">
        YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Version 2**

This is absolutely not working flawless, and getting quite complex already, but I think it can be made better when calculating a more accurate `hoverX` and `hoverY`.
What this version does is:

- storing the mouse position when hovering the loader
- hide the loader just to select the element in the document by x/y coördinates
- scroll the found element or the first parent that can scroll

When hovering and scrolling around you'll see it's not really meeting the expactations of the user, but in the end you can see everything.
To make it better you should take into account already scrolled elements when storing, or using, `hoverX`/`hoverY`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loader").css('height', $('#content').height());
    $("#loader").css('width', $('#content').width());
    $("#loader-scroll").css('height', '2000'); // TODO iterate the 'content' div and calculate needed height
});

$('#loader').on('mouseover', function(event){
    $(this).data('hoverX', event.clientX);
  $(this).data('hoverY', event.clientY);
});

$('#loader').on('scroll', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let $loader = $(this);
    $loader.css('z-index', -1);
    
    let element = document.elementFromPoint($loader.data('hoverX'), $loader.data('hoverY'));
    $loader.css('z-index', 9999);
   console.log('element under pointer: ' + element.tagName + ' #' + element.getAttribute('id'));
   let scrolled = scrollFirstScrollable(element, document.getElementById('content'), event.target.scrollTop);
   if(scrolled === false){
    console.log('did not scroll background element');
   }else{
    console.log('scrolled: ' + element.tagName + ' #' + element.getAttribute('id'));
    }
});

function scrollFirstScrollable(element, lastElement, amount){
  while(element){
    if(element.scrollHeight <= element.clientHeight){
      if(element === lastElement){
        return false;
      }
        element = element.parentElement;
    }else{
      element.scrollTop = amount;
        return element;
    }
  }
}


$('#content, #content div, button').each(function(){

    console.log(this.tagName + ' #' + this.getAttribute('id') + ' - ' + this.getAttribute('style'));
  console.log({'clientHeight': this.clientHeight, 'scrollheight': this.scrollHeight});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position: relative">
  <div id="loader"
    style="
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: red;
      opacity: 0.4;
      z-index: 9999;
      overflow:auto;
       /* display:none; */
    "><div id="loader-scroll">
  </div></div>

  <div id="content" style="width:200px;">
  
  <div id="subcontent-1" style="height: 200px; overflow: auto">
    <div id="subcontent-1-1" style="height: 1000px; background-color: blue;">
      <button onclick="alert('YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME!')">
        YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME
      </button>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="subcontent-2" style="height: 200px; overflow: auto">
  
    <div id="subcontent-2-1" style="height: 1000px; background-color: yellow;">
      <button onclick="alert('YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME!')">
        YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME, TOO!
      </button>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Imho the best solution so far. But I've adopted the question a bit, check if you could adopt it to these requiretments.

Comment: IMHO the idea itself meets the requirements you added.  The ids should be replaced by classes and your plugin should handle a connection between the content elements and their respective loaders (or other way around).

Comment: The problem with this approach is, that it assumes there is only a single scrollable div blocked by the "loading-div". But it can be set on top of a div containing multiple, scrollable elements. Check my modified sample.

Comment: I added another variant, my last input :)

Comment: Thank you so much! But yes, it is's starting to get too hacky :/

Answer (score 0):

the first markup is using transparent overlay on top of a scrolling element, preventing any interactions with the content underneath by setting the overlay's position to absolute and its opacity to 50%

now in modified markup, by using `top: unset` and allowing the content underneath to be clickable. then by setting `pointer-events: none` style to the button, makeing it unclickable. so to make it clickable again included a js function which sets `pointer-events: unset` style to the button when the scrolling event is triggered.

```js
function addPointerEvents() {
  const sys3 = document.querySelector('.sys3');
  const btn = document.querySelector('button');

  sys3.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  sys3.addEventListener('touchscroll', handleScroll);

  function handleScroll() {
    btn.style.pointerEvents = 'unset';
  }
}

addPointerEvents();
```

```html
<div style="position: relative">
  <div
    style="
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: unset;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: white;
      opacity: 0.5;
    "
  ></div>

  <div class="sys3" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: auto">
    <div style="height: 1000px">
      <button onclick="alert('YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME!')" style="pointer-events: none;">
        YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

hope it is as it was intended by the OP based on my understanding.

Comment: I've adjusted the question a bit, give it a look.

Comment: @tris right now it is doing the same, just with diff approach

Comment: No, this approach disables **all** buttons. I want to disable **all pointer events** on all controls **below** the loading-div.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily disable all the pointer events for the element by adding an extra almost-transparent overlay over the scrollable items

```css
.foo {
  position: relative;
}
.foo::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  right: 0; bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.1;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
<div style="position: relative; display: flex">
  <div
    style="
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: blue;
      opacity: 0.1;
      pointer-events: none;
    "
  ></div>

  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: auto">
    <div style="height: 1000px" class="foo">
      <button onclick="alert('YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME!')">
        YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: auto">
    <div style="height: 1000px" class="foo">
      <button onclick="alert('YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME!')">
        YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME, TOO!
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="position: relative; display: flex">
  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: auto">
    <div style="height: 1000px">
      <button onclick="alert('Im still useable!')">
        I'm still useable
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect solution, but I don't know the context where you would use it. So, alternatively, you can calculate whether you find elements UNDER `.blocked` and, if it is not scrolled, to add `pointer-events: none;` to it.

P.S. Most likely, this is not an ideal solution. Also in the example I added the (optional) `.blocked-wrapp` and `.blocked-exclude` classes to avoid looping through ALL elements.

```js
const disabledElements = (blockedClass, wrappClass, excludeClass) => {
  const { left, top, width, height } = document.querySelector(`.${blockedClass}`).getBoundingClientRect();
  const selector = wrappClass ? `.${wrappClass} *` : '*';
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(el => {
    if (
         el.classList.contains(`${blockedClass}`)
      || el.querySelector(`.${blockedClass}`)
      || el.classList.contains(excludeClass)
      || el.closest(`.${excludeClass}`)
    ){
      return;
    }
    el.style.removeProperty('pointer-events');
    const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    if (computedStyle.overflow === 'auto' || computedStyle.overflow === 'scroll') {
      return;
    }
    const { left: l, top: t, width: w, height: h } = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (l >= left && l + w <= left + width && t >= top && t + h <= top + height) {
      el.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    }
  })
}

disabledElements('blocked', 'blocked-wrapp', 'blocked-exclude');
window.onresize = () => disabledElements('blocked', 'blocked-wrapp', 'blocked-exclude');
```

```html
<div
  class="blocked-wrapp"
  style="display: flex;"
>
<div style="position: relative; display: flex">
  <div
    class="blocked"
    style="
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: white;
      opacity: 0.5;
      pointer-events: none;
    "
  ></div>

  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
    <div style="height: 1000px">
      <button onclick="alert('YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME!')">
        YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: auto">
    <div style="height: 1000px">
      <button onclick="alert('YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME!')">
        YOU CANNOT TRIGGER ME, TOO!
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="position: relative; display: flex" class="blocked-exclude">
  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: auto">
    <div style="height: 1000px">
      <button onclick="alert('Im still useable!')">
        I'm still useable
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```