# jQuery getJSON request returning empty response - same domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I've been searching for a while for an explanation to this issue but getting no where...

I have a jQuery getJSON request:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/context/json/removeEntity.html", {
    contentId : 1,
    entIndex : entityIndex
}, onRemoveEntityResponse);
```

Made from the URL: *http://localhost:8080/context/entity.html?contentId=2* (**same domain and port**).

My response as seen via firebug in Firefox (5) and Chrome is empty. What's also interesting is that I have put a break point in my Java code that serves the JSON request and *it is* hit, but only after Firefox decides the request is complete.

I have also debugged some of the jQuery and here are some of the variables involved in the AJAX response handling (jQuery 1.5.2 un-minified):

**[Line: 6651] deferred.rejectWith( callbackContext, [ jqXHR, statusText, error ] )**

```
jqXHR: { readyState:0, responseText:"", status:0, statusText:"error", ...})
statusText: "error"
error: ""
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Ignore the fact that the URL requests an HTML file, it's not really HTML, we use [Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/) with [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html) to provide mappings to JSP files and Java controllers.

The JSON that should be returned by my Java controller is as follows (and is if I go to the URL directly):

```
{"oldEntityIndex":1,"isSuccess":true,"entityWasSaved":false}
```

Comment: Why is it an HTML file? Also can you please show the JSON?

Comment: And Firebug tells you that the request has been successful?

Comment: No, it is all red but there is no response code next to the request URL like there would normally be for a 200, 404, 403, etc.

Comment: And you're sure that the server returns proper JSON?

Comment: Fairly - I'm using a Java JSON library to output a JSON string; http://www.json.org/java/ and it shouldn't really matter at this stage anyway since the break point in my Java code gets hit after jQuery has starting handling the 'response'.

Comment: Have you tried with relative URL? Also check whether you are getting OPTIONS request instead of GET on the server for Access Control Headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My stupidity - a jQuery plugin I had written (and included in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290254/how-to-order-events-bound-with-jquery/6152570#6152570)) had a bug in it.

The plugin had removed the `onclick` attribute of the element that sent the AJAX request off and bound it using jQuery `bind`, but what I had forgotten to do with the `onclick` handler was return the result. Hence my `onclick` handler returning `false` and preventing the browser from following the underlying link was ignored, I guess the browser then cancelled the AJAX request since it knew it was about to move to a new page.

Wasted time! Sorry.