# How can I run code right before the jQuery submit() executes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I have a form and a validation function that executes when a form is submitted. However, I want some other codes to run before the validation runs. I tried this: [How to order events bound with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290254/how-to-order-events-bound-with-jquery), but it does not work.

Here's what I have:

```
  $('form').submit(function(){
    $('form').trigger('before-submit');

    if($(this).find('error').exists(event))
      event.preventDefault();
  });


  $('form').bind('before-submit', function(e) {
    if($('#url').val=='http://')
      $('#url').val('');
      alert('test');
  });
```

Comment: Why not *literally* put a call to "some other codes" right before you do the validation?

Comment: The first part is in an external file, the second part is generated with PHP.

Comment: You could still have a call to a function right before the validation, and then define that function somewhere else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do:

```
$(function() {
     $('#formLogin').submit( function() {
         alert("Something"); //do something else here
         return true;
     });
});
```

Comment: This is not answer to this question and does not solve the problem in any way.

Comment: @MartinJaneček this code runs before form submit() executes, doesnt it..? and i guess this is wat OP wants... else i guess it would not be Accepted as correct answer..!

Comment: no, it doesnt - simulated it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/envxddwa/) - `Something` will not show up before `external (validation)`.
Commenting this right because it is Accepted as corrent answer while it doesn't solve asked problem.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  beforeSubmit(function(){
    // this function is the 'callback' function
    if($(this).find('error').exists(event))
      event.preventDefault();
  });
});

function beforeSubmit(fn) {
  if($('#url').val=='http://'){
    $('#url').val('');
    alert('test');
  }
  // call the 'callback' function you gave as argument
  fn();
}
```

Comment: hi Sander, Your solution work for me. Thanks. 
Now, how can implement success/failure/complete functions ?