# Returning false in first of multiple form submission handlers

Tags: jquery

I have two submit handlers, one validating a form and one submitting the form:

```
// validates the form but does not submit it
$("form").submit(function() {
  // perform validation here and set "validationFails" appropriately
  // ...
  if (validationFails) {
    return false;
  }
});

// submits the form via ajax
$("form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // submit the form via ajax here
  // ...
});
```

It seems like the form should not be submitted via ajax if validation fails because `return false` is used, and so the subsequent `submit` handler in the chain should not be called. However, even if validation fails, the form is submitted via ajax. Why?

Comment: have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger like Firebug or Chrome Developer?

Comment: why complicate things by using two form submit handlers, just create one and add any function calls to it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290254/how-to-order-events-bound-with-jquery

Comment: This is in a large Web app that uses common validation across the app (hence the first submit handler), and uses a specific submission handler for the specific section of the app (hence the second handler). The handlers are in different files, and the first handler shown above is loaded and attached first.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Returning `false` from an event handler is the equivalent of calling both `event.preventDefault()` and [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), that is, it prevents the default action for the event from happening and it stops the event bubbling up the DOM tree. It does *not* stop other handlers on the same element from running.

You need to call the [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()` method](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) - that stops other handlers bound to the same element from running, noting that the handlers will be run in the same order they are bound so you (obviously) have to bind your validation handler first.

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
  // perform validation here and set "validationFails" appropriately
  // ...
  if (validationFails) {
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: is there a way to let the other handlers resume, after "stopImmediatePropagation" and do some work?

Comment: @emfi - Where would you try to do that from? After the handler in which `stopImmediatePropagation()` is called finishes that will be the end of processing for the current event.

Comment: ah, okay... i would like to something like that: replace the current handler with another one, and if the new one is completed, re-bind and trigger the old one

Comment: How can I make sure the second handler is called **after** the validation one?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger - as I said in my answer, jQuery calls the handlers in the order they were bound.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `event` argument in the second `submit` handler and also you need to stop the event propagation from first `submit` handler when validation fails.

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
  // validate...
  if (validationFails) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      return false;
  }
});

$("form").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
     // submit the form via ajax
});
```

Comment: The first was a typo on my part. I will try your other suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding "event.stopPropagation()" did not correct the problem (since that "return false" does stop propagation itself).

Comment: I added an ellipsis to the code in the question to denote where the code occurs.

Comment: The order of attaching `form` submit event handlers is important in your code. Make sure you attach the submit handler to do ajax submit after the one for validation handler.

Comment: Can you put console.log() in both the handlers and check the sequence?

Answer (score -3):

Your logic is incorrect that the 2 handlers are talking to each other. Use only one handler. Return false if validation fails, submit via ajax if it doesn't fail

Comment: This is in a large Web app that uses common validation across the app (hence the first submit handler), and uses a specific submission handler for the section of the app (hence the second handler). The handlers are in different files, and the first handler shown above is loaded and attached first.

Comment: WOuld be better then to unbind "submit" then bind one handler to manage the process