# jquery setting the order of handlers

Tags: jquery

I have a class of div MyClass I want to hook up to two handlers. This class is generated dynamically and this is what I'm doing:

```
$('#MainDiv').on({
 click: function () { Handler1($(this)); }
}, '.MyClass');

$('#SpecialChildDiv').on({
 click: function () { Handler2($(this)); }
}, '.MyClass');
```

**How do I control which handler is called first?** Handler2 does some additional work but it's not called on every MyClass because it's not in the SpecialChildDiv. I want Handler 2 to be called AFTER Handler1.

Thanks.

Comment: That is TWO different handlers... I am not sure what you asking...

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is `'.myClass'` supposed to be doing there at the end?  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I suspect it works from inside out.

Comment: @mblase75 ".on( events-map [, selector] [, data] )"  it's the selector.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Ahh, it was the unnecessary events-map that threw me.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: yes, there are more events than the click but the tow handler problem only applies on the click event problem.

Comment: The way you bind the handlers will not allow you to control their priority. And personally I find this to be good thing.

Comment: @frenchie That's not what I meant. ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to order events bound with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290254/how-to-order-events-bound-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `SpecialChildDiv` is presumably a descendant of `MainDiv`, it will be called first. This is because the event bubbles up from the target, and invokes handlers found along the way up in that order.

One possibility would be to  make the call to `Handler2` in the `SpecialChildDiv` handler *asynchronous* by using a `setTimeout`.

```
$('#MainDiv').on({
   click: function () { 
       Handler1($(this)); 
   }
}, '.MyClass');

$('#SpecialChildDiv').on({
   click: function () { 
       setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
           Handler2($(this));
       }, this), 0);
   }
}, '.MyClass');
```

So the handler itself will be invoked right away, but your `Handler2` function won't run until the after the `Handler1` has been called.

I've also used `$.proxy` to retain the correct `this` value in the function you pass to `setTimeout`.

---

A little off topic, but you can make your code cleaner if you change `Handler1` and `Handler2` so that `this` is a reference to the element, instead of passing it as an argument...

```
$('#MainDiv').on({
   click: Handler1
}, '.MyClass');

$('#SpecialChildDiv').on({
   click: function () { 
       setTimeout($.proxy(Handler2, this), 0);
   }
}, '.MyClass');
```

You'll just need to do `$(this)` inside your functions to wrap the element in a jQuery object. Though this may not be useful if there are other arguments to pass.

---

Based on your comment below, it seems that this technique will need to be applied to various descendant elements.

To DRY up the code, you can create a factory for your click handlers...

```
function async_handler_factory(the_handler) {
    return function() {
        setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
           the_handler($(this));
        }, this), 0);
    };
}
```

...then use it like this...

```
$('#MainDiv').on({
   click: Handler1
}, '.MyClass');

$('#SpecialChildDiv').on({
   click: async_handler_factory(Handler2)
}, '.MyClass');

$('#AnotherChildDiv').on({
   click: async_handler_factory(Handler3)
}, '.MyClass');
```

So it's the same principle. Just that you pass your `HandlerN` function to `async_handler_factory`, and it will create and return the `click` handler function, which does the same as my original code by invoking the `HandlerN` in a `setTimeout`.

---

Just to avoid confusion about `$.proxy`, here's an updated version that eliminates it.

```
function async_handler_factory(the_handler) {
    return function() {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
           the_handler($(self));
        }, 0);
    };
}
```

This shows that it's actually the `setTimeout` that is making your solution work.

---

*EDIT: Had a different name for `async_handler_factory` in different places. Fixed.*

Comment: The guys who built jquery really thought of everything!! Thanks for introducing me to this proxy function!

Comment: @frenchie: You're welcome. Yeah the `$.proxy` comes in handy, and I think is a little nicer than doing `var self = this;` then `Handler2($(self));`

Comment: I just thought of something: is there a way to make it work the other way around? In other words, instead of having the proxy function work in SpecialChildDiv, have it work with MainDiv? There are actually several different SpecialChildDiv and I want to avoid the proxy issue for every case.

Comment: @frenchie: I'm not certain what you mean. The `$.proxy` just returns a function with the proper `this` value bound. It's the `setTimeout` that is allowing the function to be invoked later. If that's what you're referring to, then no. By then time the handler for `MainDiv` is invoked, it's already too late. The handler for any descendants have already run.

Comment: @frenchie: ...one possibility to perhaps simplify the code a bit would be to create a factory function that generates a function like the one I did above. It'll still be applied to each descendant, but it'll make things cleaner. Give me a minute, and I'll update.

Comment: ok, very cool idea with the handler factory!! Thank you very much for the time you spent; others who'll come to this page will like it too! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So don't call the second one on click -- call it after the first handler is done:

```
$('#MainDiv').on({
    click: function (e) { 
        Handler1($(this)); 
        if ($(e.target).attr('id')==="SpecialChildDiv") {
            specialChildClick();
        }
    }
}, '.MyClass');

specialChildClick = function () {
    Handler2($('#SpecialChildDiv')); 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of doing this but it's messy in my case. The MyClass is actually a date on a custom calendar and I want to keep the logic of the calendar separate from the logic of the other control that uses the calendar.