# How to call previously bound event after the current?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

This question came to my mind when I was experimenting with multiple events bound to the same object. Still I'm trying to find the most simple solution.

Imagine we have this markup:

```
​<select class="class1 class2">
    <option>Value 1</option>
    <option>Value 2</option>
    <option>Value 3</option>
</select>
​<p></p>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And two methods bound to `select` for `change` event:

```
$(".class1").on("change", function() {
    // first method for change
    $("p").append("<div>Event for class1</div>");
});

$(".class2").on("change", function() {
    // second method for change
    $("p").append("<div>Event for class2</div>");
});
```

​
Now if you make selection change the content of `p` will be:

```
Event for class1
Event for class2
```

My 'research' question is how to rewrite the **second** `on` handler in order to make it fire its handler **first**. So finally the content of `p` should be:

```
Event for class2
Event for class1
```

The situation is so that we are unable to swap `on` statements in the source.

What ideas do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are solutions for this. One example is the [`preBind` by Jonathan Conway](https://gist.github.com/1046209).

This plugin manipulates jQuery's event handler list for an element and adds an event at the front of it instead at the end.

So you use `$(...).preBind` where you used `bind` earlier. This does not apply to `$(...).on` but similar solution could be easily made from this.

This however is something I would **strongly advise you not to do**, as events competing for first place is often sign of bad architecture.

Comment: Thanks for really useful issues! Of course, I will not build up the architecture with such 'problems' but descibed situation might happen.

Answer (score 1):

First, though it may not be the aim of your research, you don't need two classes to bind events to handlers.  You could just call `$(".class1").on(...);` twice.

Second, handler execution order should not be important, but I understand that this is pure testing/research.

About your question, two options come to mind...

1.- Unbind/bind events, if possible.  Code would be like this:

```
$(".class1").on("change", function() {
    // first method for change
    $("p").append("<div>Event for class1</div>");
});

// Unbind event, then bind again
$(".class1").off("change").on("change", function() {
    // second method for change
    $("p").append("<div>Event for class2</div>");
    $("p").append("<div>Event for class1</div>");
});
```

2.- As in question [How to order events bound with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290254/how-to-order-events-bound-with-jquery), create your own event:

```
$(".class1").on("change", function() {
    // first method for change
    $("p").append("<div>Event for class1</div>");
});

// Bind custom event
$(".class1").on("myCustomEvent", function() {
    // first method for change
    $("p").append("<div>Event for class1</div>");
});

$(".class2").off("change").on("change", function() {
    // second method for change
    $("p").append("<div>Event for class2</div>");

    // Trigger custom event
    $(".class1").trigger("myCustomEvent");
});
```