# Can you arrange the bubble order of event callbacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, event-handling

I have several objects listening for a `change` event, but I need them to fire off in a designated order.

Is it possible to customize the bubble order of several binded objects in jQuery?

Comment: They will bubble upwards through the DOM, I believe.

Comment: Can you set up an example to demonstrate what you want to happen?

Comment: Nope. It only bubbles up. It would be possible to write something to fire things top down, but it would be better if you tell us why things need to be in that specific order of yours.

Comment: Maybe this might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290254/how-to-order-events-bound-with-jquery

Comment: You could use deferred objects to get this effect, but i suspect *bubble* isn't really what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, you cannot customize event bubble order.

To achieve the effect you desire, I would recommend **jQuery custom events**.

Example:

```
$("#YOURELEMENT").trigger('CUSTOMEVENT'); //create a new custom event
$("#YOURELEMENT2").bind('CUSTOMEVENT',function(e){ ... }); //listen for new custom event
```

Here's a [good tutorial](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-custom-events-they-will-rock-your-world/) on it.

Comment: So the custom event would toggle which action was performed first through indexing. Clever architectural idea here..

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've experienced, there is an array of handlers which stores all the handlers referring the assigned functions. So when ever you add a new function for an event, it goes at the end of that array which means something like the code below:

```
$("SomeElement")
.live(
    {
        click: function ()
        {
            // This is handler named A.
            alert("A");
        }
    }
);

$("SomeElement")
.live(
    {
        click: function ()
        {
            // This is handler named B.
            alert("B");
        }
    }
);
```

B will be shown **after** A when `"click"` event triggered.

But when you change the places:

```
$("SomeElement")
.live(
    {
        click: function ()
        {
            // This is handler named B.
            alert("B");
        }
    }
);

$("SomeElement")
.live(
    {
        click: function ()
        {
            // This is handler named A.
            alert("A");
        }
    }
);
```

B will be shown **before** A when `"click"` event triggered.

You can order the adding handlers this way because the javascript code executes from in an up-down direction and I believe it's the only way.

Hope it helps.

Cheers