# onClick priority over addEventListener in javascript?

Tags: javascript, onclick, handler, addeventlistener

Right now, I have an event listener that listens to a click on the screen. There is also a button on the screen. When I click on the button the event listener will execute before the onclick. Is there a way I can make onclick have higher priority?

```
<script>
document.body.addEventListener('click',function(){alert('1');}, false);

function clicked() { 
    alert('2');
}
</script>
<button onclick="clicked()">Click this</button>
```

Clicking the button also triggers the event handler. 1 shows before 2, when I click the button. I want 2 to show first.

Comment: Can you provide some code please?

Comment: you are missing the `function` keyword right before your `clicked()` definition

Comment: In this fiddle you'll see that 2 shows before 1 ... as it should. Your problem must be somewhere else: http://jsfiddle.net/wte5dpq8/4/

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`addEventListner`'s third argument is the [`useCapture` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). If you set it to `true`, handler will be executed while the event is traveling **down** to the `button` element. However, if you set it to `false`, the handler will be triggered while the event is bubbling up:

```
  capture phase  | |  / \ bubbling up
-----------------| |--| |-----------------
| element1       | |  | |                |
|   -------------| |--| |-----------     |
|   |element2    \ /  | |          |     |
|   --------------------------------     |
|        W3C event model                 |
------------------------------------------
```

From: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link4

In your example, the `onclick` **should be executed *before* the click handler on the `body` tag**. If you want to reverse the order of execution, you should `capture` the event at `body`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use inline differently. When `.addEventListener` need to wait for DOM, on the other hand inline `onclick` binds while DOM is loading.

```
<script>
document.body.addEventListener('click',function(){alert('1');}, false);

function clicked() { 
    alert('2');
}
</script>
<button onclick="alert('2');">Click this</button>
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/8j9q23jw/