# Define function to be invoked first on onclick event using addEventListener or other method

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events

I have legacy JS code which I don't what to touch defined in script `A.js`. It have simple onclick event and function attached to it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //jquery onclick 
    $("#create_button").click(function (e) {
    ..... 
    }
}    
    //html
     <button class="btn btn-primary" id="create_button"
                                            name="create_button">
                                        Create New app
                                    </button>
```

Then to add functionality to this button I'm defining in doing this is loading in my second script script `B.js` which comes after `A.js`:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    document.getElementById("create_button").addEventListener("click", () => {
                                      self.MyFirstFunction()
                     }, false);

}
```

How can I defined that self.MyFirstFunction() will always trigger the first?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you force your Javascript event to run first, regardless of the order in which the events were added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979961/how-do-you-force-your-javascript-event-to-run-first-regardless-of-the-order-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `useCapture` to true when adding event listener to the element:

> For event listeners attached to the event target, the event is in the target phase, rather than the capturing and bubbling phases. Event listeners in the “capturing” phase are called before event listeners in any non-capturing phases.

```js
$('#element').click(function(){
  console.log("first registered Handler in source code")
})

document.getElementById("element").addEventListener("click",function(e){
console.log("second registered Handler in source code")},true); // Notice the last argument is true
```

```css
#element{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background:lightgreen;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the [`useCapture`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) flag of the `eventListener` to give it the highest priority over other `eventListeners`.

**In your case:**

`scriptB.js`

```js
$(window).on("load", function () {
    document
        .getElementById("create_button")
        .addEventListener("click", () => self.MyFirstFunction(), true);
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
let button = document.querySelector("#button")

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("I was added first")
})

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("I was added second")
}, true)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Demo Button</button>
```