# Set execution order of event-handlers of click event in jQuery?

Tags: event-handling, handler, jquery

I am using jQuery 1.9.1.

Suppose i have a button with id="clickMe"
My jQuery code is:

```
$('#clickMe').click(function(event)
{
    eventHandler1();//do something
    eventHandler2();//use output from eventHandler1() and do something
}
```

Now, i want "eventHandler2" to be executed at last so that i could use the output of "eventHandler1". Is there any way to do this manually and not just the way i have put the handlers inside the click event?
One more thing, "eventHandler1()" and "eventHandler2()" are present in different .js files and thus the requirement.

Comment: does you eventHandler1() uses any async request to server?

Comment: i can tell you that all these handlers work without page reload

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to order events bound with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290254/how-to-order-events-bound-with-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [`jQuery.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) provides a way to execute callback functions based on one or more objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

For example, when the Deferreds are `jQuery.ajax()` requests, the arguments will be the `jqXHR objects` for the requests, in the order they were given in the argument list.

```
$.when(eventHandler1).then(eventHandler2).done(function(){
 alert('done.');
});
```

Comment: thanks mate! even though i found another way of dealing with my not-so-complex problem, this approach surely works :)

Comment: Oh Great and glad this helped.

Answer (score 1):

So can even use `GLOBAL` variable to store `eventHandler1` output and access that inside `eventHandler2`

**Example**

```
var someVar;

function eventHandler1()
{
   // process
   someVar = some value from process
   return someVar;
}

function eventHandler2()
{
   alert(someVar);
}
```

**Response to OP comment**

as you have asked about execute handler in queue you can use `Jai` answer.

you can use `.when` `.then` and `.done` as below.

```
$.when(eventHandler1).then(eventHandler2).done(function(){
  //process code
});
```

Comment: eventHandler1() dynamically filters the data.it is a long plug-in.i would rather not make any changes there...just want to make eventHandler2() the last to execute

Comment: @spyder so you can use `jQuery.done()` handler to make sure that eventHandler 1 is finished.

Comment: @spyder see Jai answer that what i mean/