# jQuery - multiple event handlers - specify order

Tags: jquery

I have two checkbox change events as follows:

1) This targets a specific checkbox:

```
$('#category').on('change', '#cars input[type=checkbox]', function(){
     //
});
```

2) And this targets all checkboxes:

```
$('#category').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(){
     //
});
```

The second event seems to be firing before the first one, but I would like the opposite instead.

How can I specify the order?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to order events bound with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290254/how-to-order-events-bound-with-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If applicable, you should try something like this instead:

```
$('#category').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(){
  if ($(this).parent().attr('id')=='cars') {
    //do for cars
  }
  //do for everything
});
```