# How can I ensure a particular click event handler executes after all other attached click handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, event-handling

I have an element:

`<div id='myButton'>Click Me!</div>`

When clicking on `myButton`, an arbitrary amount of click event handlers will fire.

For example, the following 3 event handlers may be attached in the following way (and order):

`$('#myButton').click(function() { alert('First function!'); });`

`$('#myButton').click(function() { alert('Third function!'); });`

`$('#myButton').click(function() { alert('Second function!'); });`

As you can maybe tell by the obscure alerts, the order in which the event handlers are attached are not necessarily the order I want them to fire in.

How can I alert 'Third Function' only once the other two click event handlers have finished?

**What I've Tried**

I've tried working with the individual event handlers via:

`$._data($('#myButton')[0], "events" ).click;`

But I can't afford to explicitly refer to the order in which the handlers are attached (so `[0]` might not be correct).

I've also tried using jQuery `when` but I suspect I'm barking up the wrong tree as the event handler is already attached and will execute in such an order unless I completely remove it.

NOTE: I don't believe this is simply a case of specifying the order of events as such, as the function I want to execute last may not be aware of the functions to be attached later on, so I can't deal with the event handlers as a collection as far as I know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to order events bound with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290254/how-to-order-events-bound-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use following snippet if you are able to set specific namespace:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() { alert('First function!'); });
$('#myButton').on("click.last", function() { alert('Third function!'); });
$('#myButton').click(function() { alert('Second function!'); });

var clicks = $._data($('#myButton')[0], "events" ).click;    

$.each(clicks, function(i, evt){
    if(evt.namespace === "last") {
        clicks.splice(clicks.length - 1, 0, clicks.splice(i, 1)[0])
    }
});
```

### --DEMO--

Comment: Thanks very much. This is exactly what I asked for in the question, so I'll mark accordingly. But (I should've been clearer about this), when would I declare `clicks`? Because at the moment, I'm not sure when the latest point in the script is, otherwise I'd just add the event handler then to ensure it's the last.

Comment: @DeeMac I'd use the window onload event handler e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/jLBT2/1/