# jquery checkbox element class click

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, jquery-click-event

I have a checkbox element that has two classes.And this classes click event ı do some stuff. onchangeofvalidationandsubquestion is always trigger first but i want to it to execute first "radior" click event than "onchangeofvalidationandsubquestion" event.Any ideas will be helpful

```
$(".radior").click(function (event) {

});

$(".onchangeofvalidationandsubquestion").click(function (event) {

});

 var $radio = $('<input  class="radiowidther" type="checkbox"  />').appendTo($div);
$radio.addClass("radior");
$radio.addClass("onchangeofvalidationandsubquestion");
```

Comment: In your code itself i see that radior is first triggered and then onchangeofvalidationandsubquestion is triggered . You can check it http://jsfiddle.net/h5zJe/

Comment: Thanks Roshan. In my page onchangeofvalidationandsubquestion is triggered first. But jsfiddle example radior is triggered first. ı am confused

Comment: In that case I think answer by Pondwater is the best.

Answer (score 1):

You could always add your own custom event to be triggered after:

```
$(".radior").click(function (event) {
    $(".onchangeofvalidationandsubquestion").trigger('myCustomEvent');
});

$(".onchangeofvalidationandsubquestion").on('myCustomEvent', function (event) {

});
```

This way the click event is guaranteed to be processed first.

Here's a quick little jsfiddle for registering and triggering custom events with jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/85XqL/

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I will try it.But Is there another way to handle it without not triggering event in the radior event?

Comment: This is probably the easiest and simplest way to guarantee event order with jQuery, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/290294/785259