# Prepend event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How can I insert event handler to the top of the queue? If I use `jquery.click()` or JavaScript `addEventListener()`, I'll have a handler at the end of queue.
What is the best way for this?
I don't want to remove the existing handler, and then adds...

Comment: Could you give us an example of a case?

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290254/how-to-order-events-bound-with-jquery

Comment: Here's a quick example: https://gist.github.com/ndugger/f0c11e4e6efa815221fb