# How to order the same element click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page containing several different scripts, and there is some click event binding to the same element. So I encounter an issue with the event order. There is code.
(for the more the script A and B is unknown).

I want execute Script A after Script B is executed.

```
//Script A
$('a').click(function (){
    alert('1')
})

//Script B
$('a').click(function (){
    alert('2')
})
```

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. If the scripts are unknown, then why does the order matter? Are you saying there's one particular script that you *do* know and you always want it to execute last?

Comment: @squint In other word, I want it to be execute first.

Comment: That's difficult. I think if you make sure your script runs first, it may get bound first and therefore execute first, but I don't know. What's the actual problem that seems to rely on the order of bound handlers?

Comment: ...do you control the code in the other scripts? Can they be changed?

Comment: @squint The different thing is the whole code is not controlled by me, I want my click event is be execute before others code. So I abstract the question. But I haven't do it better.

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290254/how-to-order-events-bound-with-jquery to see if they work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that you have two scripts: `script1.js` and `script2.js`. Both of them attach event handlers to the same element. `script1.js` is currently loaded in before `script2.js`.

Right now, the handler in `script1.js` will execute before the handler in `script2.js`. There are a few ways of changing this:

1. Swap the load order. Make sure that `script2.js` loads before `script1.js`.
2. Attach the handler in `script1.js` to a unique event and trigger it from `script2.js`.

Example:

```
// script1.js
$('a').on('custom-event', function(e) {
  // do stuff
});

// script2.js
$('a').click(function(e) {
  // do stuff
  $(this).trigger('custom-event', e);
});
```