# jQuery control order of click events

Tags: jquery

Let's say we have this:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "div", function() {
    console.log(1);
});

$("div").on("click", function() {
    console.log(2);
});
```

Now when I click on the `<div>`, the output is:

```
2
1
```

Is there a way to have the opposite order, given the fact that **I can't modify the selectors or change the order**?

**EDIT**

My current workaround is a `setTimeout()`, but I'd prefer not to have this since it creates ugly glitches.

Comment: Just interchange the console.log() of both events ;)

Comment: I think that the second one will always fire first, as it's bound to a `div`. This means that the users clicks on the `div`, then the event bubbles up and hits the first event that's bound to the body.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to order events bound with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290254/how-to-order-events-bound-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

The event propagates up trough DOM, so there's no practical way of forcing click on body to fire before the click on div does. However, a simple workaround to this issue would be following:

```
var somethingOrOther = function() {
  console.log(1);
}

$(document.body).on("click", "div", function() {
    somethingOrOther();
});

$("div").on("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    somethingOrOther();
    console.log(2);
});
```

[event.stopPropagation();](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) ensures that the click won't bubble further up the DOM and click on body won't trigger, but only when clicking the div.

Answer (score 0):

You said nothing about modifying callback function

```
$(document.body).on("click", "div", function() {
   setTimeOut(function(){ console.log(1);},5});
});

$("div").on("click", function() {
    console.log(2);
});
```