# how to set which $('.test').click function to trigger 1st

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 `$('.test).click` function, with same name, how do I choose which to be triggered 1st?

- this `$('.test).click(function () {})` are located in 2 different .js file, however it will be combine when in the webpage
- I'm not suppose to touch the 1st .js as it's come out of box with piwik, hence the reason I use `$('.test).click(function () {})` on another js

So is there a way to decide which `$('.test).click(function () {})`  get triggered 1st?

Thanks

Comment: instead of having class selectors Use id selectors to differentiate. eg: $('#test1).click(function () {}), $('#test2).click(function () {})

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to order events bound with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290254/how-to-order-events-bound-with-jquery)

Comment: use only one function and validate it inside . Add some checks to decide which to run and which not

Comment: Hi @Sameer, unfortunately the original html which i'm not suppose to touch too, doesn't have id but only class