# Event.PreventDefault() doesn't always work

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I just wanted to make a quick userscript to prevent websites from opening links in new tabs, so I can choose when to do so. Oh boy.

I wanted to use plain javascript; I think it's enough for such an easy task. I was doing all my tests in Quora because that's where I decided I wanted to code that little snippet.

Well, nothing worked. I started simple and went increasing the craziness of my code in light of the failure: **the link kept opening** no matter how many preventDefault()'s, return false's, prevent[*]Propagation(), eventListeners... Even modifying the dom to strip the `a` element from its target="_blank".

In the end, I bit my tongue and tried jQuery with this little snippet:

```
$("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Was preventDefault() called: " + event.isDefaultPrevented());
    });
```

But that didn't do any good either. So I gave up. I then realized that the code seemed to work on other websites. Except on Quora.com. A regular Quora link looks like this:

```
<a href="http://thewebsite.to/go"
    rel="noopener nofollow"
    target="_blank"
    onclick="return Q.openUrl(this);"
    class="external_link"
    data-qt-tooltip="thewebsite.to"
    data-tooltip="attached">
    Link text
</a>
```

There's plenty of crap there, for sure, but I've been stripping down attributes one by one until the bare bones: `<a href="http://thewebsite.to/go"></a>` and still doesn't work. Best of all is that even though the link opens, `event.isDefaultPrevented()` returns true!

Why does that happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: That has an inline event handler. Is that dynamically created?

Comment: It's likely, why?

Answer (score 0):

You are sure that links getting selected?
Maybe this help:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: $(document).on('click','a', function(e) {  is more specific and fast.

Comment: @A.T. i changed it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the onclick definition in the a tag. It creates a new on click event listener before your code does anything.

To  prevent it you will have to play around with the event order, see this previous question: [How to order events bound with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290254/how-to-order-events-bound-with-jquery)