# How to fire click event that was attached later before click event attached earlier via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

```js
//First click handler added via a plugin whose files I do not wish to change
jQuery('.element').click(function(){
console.log('click event 1');
});

//2nd click handler - need this to be executed before the 1st 
jQuery('.element').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="element">Click Here</div>
```

I have the following code that attaches a click event to some elements:

```
$('.element').click(function(){
console.log('click event 1');
});
```

After the above code if executed, the following code attaches 2nd click event handler to the same element:

```
$('.element').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Event though the 2nd block of code has `event.preventDefault()`,`event.stopPropagation()`,the first function is executed. How to change the execution order such that the 2nd block of code is executed first on click event?

Comment: Why not delete the first click handler if you don't want it to execute?

Comment: The first block is added via a plugin and I do not want to make changes to the plugin files. That will be the last option if there's no way to accomplish the above.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet editor. Post RELEVANT HTML, JS and CSS and click on the left to get the jQuery framework. You can edit the link if the version is not there.

Comment: Also use `.on` and perhaps delegation to handle this

Comment: *"I do not want to make changes to the plugin files"*: you don't have to. Are you sure that plugin has attached the handler with `.click` -- which is a [deprecated method](https://api.jquery.com/click-shorthand/)?

Comment: I have changed the code from `.click` to `.on('click',function` in both the code blocks but the behavior is still the same.

Comment: [How to order events bound with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/290254/1427878) has a couple of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

So this does not work because the first event handler is executed first

```js
$('.element').on("click", function() {
  console.log('click event not under my control yet');
});

$("#container").on("click", ".element", function(event) {
  // Your logic here to decide whether to allow the original event handler
  var shouldAllowEvent = false /* your condition */ ;

  if (!shouldAllowEvent) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }

  console.log('intercepted event')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <a href="#" class="element">Click</a><br/>
  <a href="#" class="element">Click</a>
</div>
```

Let's turn it off

```js
$('.element').on("click", function() {
  console.log('click event not under my control yet');
});

// Step 1: Unbind the existing event handler
$('.element').off("click");

// Step 2: Bind YOUR event handler to the container
$("#container").on("click", ".element", function(event) {
  var shouldAllowEvent = false; // Your condition

  if (!shouldAllowEvent) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log('Event intercepted and blocked');
  }
});

// Step 3: Re-bind the "original" event handler if you know it. If not, it is not trivial to get it back
$('.element').on("click", function() {
  console.log('click event NOW under my control');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <a href="#" class="element">Click</a><br/>
  <a href="#" class="element">Click</a>
</div>
```